# How can you give your mobile web app an install screen?

Tags: ios, web-applications, mobile

Similar to how [forecast.io](http://www.forecast.io) does it -  if you visit their website on your phone. this shows up:

[image: forecast.io]

Once you add it to your home screen, the rest of the app becomes available.

Comment: maybe this article is the right thing for you: http://appcropolis.com/howto/running-iphone-webapps-from-the-home-screen-only/ explains how to build a fork between `started in browser` and `started from home screen`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
window.navigator.standalone
```

will result in `true` if you have launched from the Home Screen or `false` if the page is open in a browser. Documented very nicely by Apple in their [Developer Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html) and works with OS 2.1 and up.

For example:

```
if (window.navigator.standalone) {
    // fullscreen mode

}
```